# How to get 'switch to plain text editor' to work?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have designed a website on Drupal. It was working fine but now when I tried to update a link (by adding any name under any option) it does not show the rich text editor. Instead it shows the plain html body.

This way :

```
<ul> Assignemnt UID </ul>
```

I mean ***switch to plain text editor*** is not working. This way I am not able to update any file or link.

How I can make this to work?

---

I am still stuck with the same problem. CKeditor does not work, instead the plain text editor gets opened. I tried everything from re-installing CKeditor to updating Drupal to newer version. When I open any heading and try to open the edit option, it runs very slow. Then when it gets open the data is visible in the form of plain text(no CKeditor). I checked the console it shows this error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience in drupal

Any help?

Comment: Are you using ckeditor as your rich text editor?

Comment: yes its regarding ckeditor.. it doesnot work for the body option but it works for the summary

Comment: so it works only for the summary huh, that's so weird... perhaps disabling and uninstalling ckeditor and then enabling it again could fix the problem.

Comment: i tried the same. no solution but

Comment: Try to switch your theme to any other and check..

Comment: are you sure? i wont loose any data. because I will be experimenting this on the live site.

Comment: You won't loose any data, but still don't experiment on live site, create a sub-site or download to local and try.

Comment: but there is no use of trying on the local. because i already have the downloaded code on local and it works fine. but it gives problem on live site.

Comment: Then it might be the php version issue. not sure.. compare both server and local versions

Comment: yes php version for both are different. can this be a reason of  issue?

Comment: no sorry php version is same. mistakenly i checked the old code. can it be a problem of jQuery?

Comment: Might be... check in the inspector whether ckeditor js file is loading..?

Comment: it shows two errors on the console.1. Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
2. POST http://nrhmhp.gov.in/ckeditor/xss

Comment: Whether these scripts loading in your site ?                                            src="sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js
 src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/full-all/lang/en.js
 src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor.styles.js
 src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/plugins/drupalbreaks/plugin.js
 src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/plugins/mediaembed/plugin.js
 src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/plugins/summary/plugin.js
 src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/full-all/plugins/tableresize/plugin.js
 and other 3 scripts ?